# Adding button on WPF data grid rows from codebehind c# code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to add a button on every row of WPF grid which I am binding from code behind. I am very new to WPF any help is appreciated.

My current code for binding grid is:

```
        DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        c1.Header = "Dummy column";
        c1.Binding = new Binding("DummyColumn");
        c1.IsReadOnly = true;
        grdDummy.Columns.Add(c1);

        foreach (DummyObject deal in AllDummyObjects)
        {
            ModelToBind dataModel = new ModelToBind()
            //do some processing on dataModel

            grdDummy.Items.Add(dataModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column with button like this:

```
    DataGridTemplateColumn buttonColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    DataTemplate buttonTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    FrameworkElementFactory buttonFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof (Button));
    buttonTemplate.VisualTree = buttonFactory;
    //add handler or you can add binding to command if you want to handle click
    buttonFactory.AddHandler(ButtonBase.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(HandleClick));
    buttonFactory.SetValue(ContentProperty, "Button");
    buttonColumn.CellTemplate = buttonTemplate;
    grdDummy.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously, an example was given of creating a Button using FrameworkElementFactory.
This class is not recommended.
[Quote from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?view=net-5.0):

> This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.

In this regard, I show the implementation code using the XamlReader.
The code is shown from the assumption that the ModelToBind class has a command-property named ButtonCommand and property ButtonTitle.
And this class is located in the local namespace "Febr20y" in the assembly of the same name.

```cs
        DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = "Dummy column",
            Binding = new Binding("DummyColumn"),
            IsReadOnly = true
        };

        DataTemplate template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(
@"<DataTemplate 
    xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
    xmlns:local='clr-namespace:Febr20y;assembly=Febr20y'
    DataType ='{x:Type local:ModelToBind}'>

    <Button Content='{Binding ButtonTitle, Mode=OneWay}'
            Command='{Binding ButtonCommand, Mode=OneWay}'/>
</DataTemplate>");
        DataGridTemplateColumn c2 = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
        {
            Header = "Buttons",
            IsReadOnly = true,
            CellTemplate=template
        };

        grdDummy.Columns.Add(c1);
        grdDummy.Columns.Add(c2);

        var listSource = AllDummyObjects
            .Select(deal => new ModelToBind() { ButtonTitle = deal.Title.ToString()})
            .ToList();
        grdDummy.ItemsSource = listSource;
```

This is equivalent to this XAML code:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="grdDummy" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DummyColumn}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Header="Dummy column"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Buttons"
                                IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ModelToBind}">
                    <Button Content="{Binding ButtonTitle, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Command="{Binding ButtonCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```